# Baixar arquivo usando react native

Tags: android, react-native

Tenho um app Android que ao ser executado acessa um arquivo e lista umas informações na tela.

A questão é que só funciona se tiver internet.

O que preciso é baixar as informações e salvar no aparelho para ser acessado offline.

Como devo fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou usar o AsyncStorage?

Para guardar a informação:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("chave", "valor");
```

Para recuperar:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("chave").then((value) => {
    // salvar no "this.state".
    this.setState({"chave": value});
}).done();
```

Abraço.

Comment: O arquivo salvo fica armazenado para ser acessado outras vezes,mesmo após o usuário fechar o app?

Comment: funciona com imagens?

Comment: Fica salvo. Para imagem você pode tentar usar esse projeto: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob